# Pythons Pandas - Converting Str object values in a column to Float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that have currently contain a column of income data stored as strings (Object). I want to convert it to float however when I used:

df['Income'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Income_2016'], errors='coerce')

and used df.dtypes, the Income is float64 however when I displayed the df the previous values that had str numbers now turned into NaN.

Before converting:

| Index | Income |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100,516 |
| 2 | 101,551 |

After converting:

| Index | Income |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NaN |
| 2 | NaN |

How do I convert it to float without converting original values as NaN?

Comment: Replace commas with dots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gotta remove the comma

Try:

```
df['Income'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Income_2016'].str.replace(',',''), errors='coerce')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
df['Income'] = df.Income_2016.apply(lambda price:float(price.replace(",","")))
```

Comment: The community [encourages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712) adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers. As explained [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837): "While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value."